# Online features ceased to work

Tags: steam, dark-souls

I'm playing Dark Souls 1 on Steam and few days ago I noticed that I can't connect to any other world: Invasions fail, White sings used by nobody, I don't see any messages. The game failed to work online before, but I always got warnings about it and Orbs would simply become unusable, which is not the case this time.
All that is tested with 2 chars in different areas.

I installed Dark Souls PVP Watchdog and confirmed that I am connected to 0 players all the time.

Reinstalling didn't help. Download region is set and the same as usual. What else can I try to fix this problem?

Comment: same happen to me over the weekend with my friends, we suspect something on steam/from software side. however, I think this  question is offtopic.

Answer (score 1):

There is one thing you should install in addition to the PvP Watchdog: DSFix. [DSFix is a very helpful mod to fix various issues in the PC version of Dark Souls.](http://blog.metaclassofnil.com/?p=652)

DSFix can change the graphics and gamplay options, and will help you get a smoother connection to other players.

The node system in general requires around 10 to 15 minutes to connect to nodes. Sometimes it happens in one minute, other times it requires 30 minutes -- there is really no way to tell as far as I know.

For an explanation of the node system, see [this link](https://www.reddit.com/r/darksouls/comments/2t2ejm/0_nodes_matchmaking_permafogwall_and_dspw/).

Comment: What do you mean? You can't do PvP rigth away from the login and need just stand and wait for 10-15 minutes? Or that node counter = 0 means nothing for first 10 minutes?

Comment: There are many ways to do PvP in Ds1 but Nodes are something diffrent and are not a indicator for PvP. The Node's you are connected to describe how many connections to other player's you have. It needs a diffrent amount of time to connect to the nodes from 2 to 25 min.  There is a very nice explanation on reddit ( https://www.reddit.com/r/darksouls/comments/2t2ejm/0_nodes_matchmaking_permafogwall_and_dspw/ )

Answer (score 1):

I did nothing, but today everything fixed itself. I saw people had the same problem a year ago and @Colin D in his comment confirmed that the same has been happened to him, so I conclude that **this was temporary server-side problem**.